# root filesystem on usb drive

Tags: linux, boot, usb, udev, root-filesystem

I am trying to move my linux partition (ext4) to usb drive and boot from this drive and not my  hdd.

I have slackware64-14.2 with kernel 5.15.25 and usb driver (xhci) **built in kernel**.

I have made the usb drive bootable (grub) but when i boot my usb drive is not recognized and i get kernel panic

Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs

So i made a simple initramfs with no module and **strangely** my usb was recognized, mounted and i booted.

But on boot, all my usb devices disconnect and reconnect.
I am sure udev is doing this with this command:

udevadm trigger --type=devices --action add

I would be grateful if any one could help me with this.
More specifically is there a way to disable udev not to disconnect only this device

But if you believe my approach is wrong, please tell me how you would to do this.

Thank you

Edit 1:
I couldnt do it with udev. so as workaround i build usb driver in kernel and it works.

Comment: What do you mean the devices are disconnected and reconnected?

Comment: I mean they act as if you have unplugged a working device and connect it again.for example as if suddenly you unplug a live usb or your hdd but it happens automatically but it mess up the whole system (file descriptor, mount point and ...). so I need to remount it but the system is on usb so i get stuck .

Comment: So you get some errors ( which ones? ) accessing files on the drive, and you check `dmesg` and see messages that indicate it was disconnected and reconnected?

Comment: i get errors like: EXT4-fs error (device, sda2)  :  __ext4_find_entry ...  and i dont have any access at system